# tweepy error with requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake

Tags: python, tweepy

I used the following code

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
screen_name =[]

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if '#selffile' in status.text.lower():
            print status.text #status.author.screen_name

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:',     status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())    
sapi.filter(locations=[5.0770049095, 47.2982950435, 15.0403900146, 54.9039819757], async=False,follow=None)
```

I got folllowing error message.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
self._start(async)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
self._run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
raise exception
requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',   'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

Does anyone have the idea to solve this problem?

`

Answer (score 0):

Twitter no longer supports SSLv3, you'll need to use TLS instead. You may need to update your version of Tweepy.